# Why does Chrome glitch when playing music with Flash player?

Tags: windows-8, google-chrome, flash

When playing music in Chrome, it often glitches and is very annoying. I tried disabling Pepper Flash and using straight Adobe Flash, but it still happens. I also restarted Chrome between disables. I have a super-fast computer so speed should not be a problem. I have updated drivers too.

[image: Imgur]

Comment: Is it when the music is coming from any site you visit that wants to play music via flash, or is it only one site that you visit regularly that has the issue?

Comment: It is from primarily music sites, Last.fm and 8Tracks. I haven't noticed Youtube doing it.

Comment: It might not be flash that is at fault then.  It could be from the sites themselves.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This doesn't currently happen, but if using this version of Chrome, try adding `--audio-buffer-size=2048` to the command line options of the shortcut. However, this will cause videos *not* to play in the current version (~50.0).